# VMWare Fusion: "No Permission to access this virtual machine"

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I had a VMWare Fusion VM backed up on my home network file server (Ubuntu). I wanted to run it again, so I copied it back to my Macbook.

When I tried to launch it in VMWare, I got an error message:

```
No permission to access this virtual machine.
Configuration file: /Users/craig/WinXP Clean + Scanner.vmwarevm/WinXP Pro Test.vmx
```

The permissions look fine to me:

- The bundle directory is 777
- The bundle files (including the listed .vmx) are all 666
- User is craig (my current user); group is staff. I changed the group to wheel at the suggestion of [this page](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/136559), but that didn't help.
- Finder shows read & write for craig, staff, and everyone on the bundle directory
- The bundle dir is also not locked
- Finder also shows rw and unlocked for the .vmx file
- The parent directory is also rw & unlocked
- Disk Utility permissions check doesn't show any problems with any of the associated files

It sure looks like I should have wide open access to run this VM; why is Fusion complaining?

Comment: Have you got any Access Control List (ACL) set. Try the -e option to ls to see

Comment: It does not appear so, as best as I can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called up VMWare Tech support to get a solution for this. After some very helpful investigation by the VMWare Tech, we eventually got it working by creating a new VM based off of the old virtual disks.

The tech speculated that copying the files off my Mac to a Samba share might have caused the permissions to become improperly set. He mentioned that copying files onto and back from a FAT volume (with its rudimentary permissions system) can occasionally fix problems like these.

Answer (score 2):

Are you the owner of all the files in the bundle recursively? At [this discussion](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1000833;jsessionid=AB40A878C5D81A962061C3AAD190D919) (at post #6), a solution to this problem is to run the following in Terminal:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER} "/Users/${USER}/Documents/Virtual Machines/Windows XP Professional.vmwarevm"
```

You'll need to replace `Windows XP Professional.vmwarevm` with `WinXP Clean + Scanner.vmwarevm` in your case.

Also, keep in mind that repairing disk permissions will **never** repair anything in your home directory. It's only applicable for Apple-installed software that are listed in /Library/Receipts.

Comment: Good advice, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. I wonder if there is a hidden xattr setting deep within the VM that was lost during the transfer to/from your Linux file server (which I'm guessing is ext4). Judging by the @ symbol on the end of the permissions for each file inside the vmwarevm bundle on my disk, I'm assuming that VMware must be using a bunch of xattr values for something.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem occur on my VM. Mine sounds like it was probably a different underlying cause than the original poster's, although the error message was exactly the same.

It turned out that I had a *.vmx.lck directory inside the bundle that must have been left over from an old execution. As soon as I deleted that directory, the problem went away and the machine was happy to start again!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using vmware-run to start the VM ? Not the fusion UI (I'm interpreting the copy-n-paste text in your post).

This might be the same problem as [VMWare Fusion 2.0.6 no longer wants to load my VMs](https://superuser.com/questions/57801/vmware-fusion-2-0-6-no-longer-wants-to-load-my-vms) - my advice there may apply here.

Comment: Nope, I am trying to use the fusion GUI. The copy-n-paste text is actually carefully-retyped text :-P

Thanks for the link though; I'll try that and see.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in getting an old vmware workstation image to work on the current vmware workstation software.  What I finally figured out from a similar cryptic message was that ACE had been enabled on the old image.  Fortunately, I had the old vmware software and was able to strip ACE out of the vmimage.  Then things worked fine on the new workstation software.

Answer (score 0):

Give proper permission to that user on the desired directory, like:

```
# chown user /work
```

Now you can choose this /work [your directory] to install VM.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a good answer but maybe it will help someone
I change the **path of install directory** of vmware and vmware installed successfully

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).